# How to append tables in Power Query while merging similar columns which have different names, types and order?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have 2 tables with similar values but different names, types and order of the columns.

What's the best way to merge them into a single table? I  believe the 2 options are **Append** or **Merge with Full Outer**.

Table1 (order 1-2-3):

```
Name    ID  Number
John    1234    324234
Steve   1230    124536
Deb     1293    968578
```

Table2 (order 3-2-1):

```
Figure  Unique  Whois
3242345 abc     Johnny
124537  fdg     Stevenson
968578  jgn     Debon
```

The merged table should look like:

```
Name        ID      Number
John        1234    324234
Steve       1230    124536
Deb         1293    968578
Johnny      abc     3242345
Stevenson   fdg     124537
Debon       jgn     968578
```

When choosing **Merge**, it allows mentioning the relations between the columns.

But when choosing **Append**, it doesn't.

[image: Excel's Power Query's Append]

So this is the result:

[image: Appended merged table]

Compare this to Merge, which fails due to different types.

[image: Excel's Power Query's Merge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Append, but first I would add steps to the **test2** query to rename the columns to match test1.  Append aligns columns using column names only (not position).

I would also change the datatype of the **ID** column in the **test1** query to Text, to accomodate the values in the **Unique** column from the **test2** query.